# What type of connector is this - Barco/Philips TSM12PHC

Tags: power-supply, identification, connector, display

I have a Barco TSM12PHC also known as Philips TSM12PHC from a cardiology. Unfortunately, I am missing the power supply. I know that the display takes 24V at 0.8A. The first three pins are positive and the last three are ground. Does anyone have any idea what kind of connector this is?

**Edit:**
So the pitch is 2mm. Attached are a few more pictures.

[image: picture of the connector]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Welcome! What’s the pin pitch and inner size of the plastic part?

Comment: Please measure the _exact_ pitch in mm: measure the center-to-center distance of the first and last pins, then divide by 5. Please show us a picture of that tab in the top of the housing from below: I want to see if it's a catch of a latch or just a boss that goes all the way back.

Comment: The last picture captures the part number, so this question should be closed I think. Look closely. It's Molex DuraClik series. I highly appreciate you posting a usable picture!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like a Molex 502352-0600 to me.

Answer (score 0):

It's the male PCB header for an unlatched, rectangular, wire-to-board connector, one of [these](https://www.digikey.ee/short/zt81qww4) (Digikey) or [these](https://connectorbook.com/identification.html?st=1&nm=by_names&bm=by_compon&c=interior_rect_conn&u=wire_to_board_conn&o=discrete_1row_w2b_conn&fl=00200000000000000000000000000000-500-%7C%7C6%7C%7C%7C) (my site).

After you measure the [exact pitch](https://www.google.com/search?q=connector+pitch) and tell us, we can narrow it down further.

Comment: I've added the pitch. Its 2mm.

Answer (score 0):

I happened across this post, and don't know if you're still looking for this info, but I am working on one of these right now, and the plug is stamped 502351. I'll attach pics of the plug.[image]